# Differential equation in a physics problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While solving a problem regarding the motion of a body considering a drag force on it I came up with this differential equation which I don't know how to solve.

$$\frac{dv}{dt} =av^2 + g$$
$~v~$ is the velocity, $~a~$ is a constant, $~g~$ is acceleration due to gravity.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It's a separable equation. In general: $$\frac{dv}{dt}=f(v)$$ Reduces to: $$\int \frac{dv}{f(v)}=t-t_0$$

Comment: In this case the integral can be expressed through the arctangent function

Comment: Note that this equation is only physical for $v<0$. The friction force in general is $-a|v|\,v$, so that the solution for $v>0$ is in hyperbolic functions.

Answer (score 2):

This equation is separable 
$$\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=av^2+g \Leftrightarrow \frac{\text{d}v}{av^2+g}=\text{d}t \Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{a}\frac{\text{d}v}{v^2+\tfrac{g}{a}}=\text{d}t$$
Integrating in both sides and taking in account that 
$$\int \frac{\text{d}x}{x^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{b}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)$$
we have that
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \text{d}t=\frac{1}{a}\int_{v_0}^{v_1}\frac{\text{d}v}{v^2+\tfrac{g}{a}}$$
$$t_1-t_0=\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{g}}\left[\arctan\left(v_1 \sqrt{\frac{a}{g}}\right)-\arctan\left(v_0 \sqrt{\frac{a}{g}}\right)\right]$$
Then, you can use that, for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)=\arctan\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: separation of variables gives

$$ \int \frac{1}{av^2+g} dv= \int 1 dt+C.$$